# Strange dark scabbing near cat's nose

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition

My male cat is about 10 months old and I noticed a strange dark spot forming in/around his nose the past couple days. Originally I thought it was simply Feline Acne, as he had some on his chin that the Vet pointed out before. His chin has cleared up, but now this nose spot has appeared. I was going to ignore it as I thought it would pass like the chin acne, but my SO thinks it looks bad enough for a trip to the Vet. It is a crusty texture like the chin acne was.

Thoughts? Acne or maybe not?

[image: Cat nose spot 1]
[image: Cat nose spot 2]

Comment: i think a vet should take a look at this,it might be normal but it can be a sign of an infection or some bleeding too,so again it is best to let the vet have a look at this.

Comment: It might be a fungal infection, which commonly starts from nostrils and spreads quickly if left untreated. It is easily curable with over the counter ointments but of course you have to consult to a professional vet before trying anything.

Comment: Yeah, the paranoia was ramping up so I made an appointment for the vet. Will be taking him in tomorrow, I'll post an update with what the vet says. Thanks to both of you for the responses!

Answer (score 5):

We took our cat to the vet and she took a sample of his skin by pressing a small piece of plastic against the irritated areas. She then ran a test on those samples and found some bacteria present within them. She believed this bacteria was due to an allergy.

Her guess was that he is allergic to his plastic water bowl, and the allergy spread from this chin to his nose (possibly from licking his face). The vet gave him a shot of antibiotics and we bought him a new stainless steel water bowl. It has only been a week now, but it looks like his face is starting to clear up. The vet told us to wait two weeks to see if he really cleared up, so we have one week to go. It is looking promising though.

Answer (score 0):

If it is blood then it needs to see the vet immediately as cats should never bleed from their nose, could also be a sign or respiratory infections or parasites

Answer (score 0):

One of our 4 cats gets the same crusty stuff around his nose.
Our vet thinks it is a food allergy condition.
For him, food testing appears to target chicken as a link.
When food containing chicken is removed from his diet the spots (slowly) reduce or disappear. 
If he eats a lot of chicken based food the spots appear, and increase, and he eventually starts wheezing a little from congestion.