# Black spots and balding on my kittys feet and face that been there for about 3 weeks help!

Tags: cats

[image]About 3 weeks my family’s kitty has been experiencing black dots around the nose that eventually spreaded around his eyes and on his feet but doesn’t seem to be affected by it

Comment: take your cat to the vet before you ask random people for advice on the net,there is a lot of missing information in your question,the age of your cat,indoor/outdoor cat,where do you live,do you have any other pets.

Comment: Another similar question with answers already: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19265/strange-dark-scabbing-near-cats-nose

Comment: Also. Be aware that orange cats have freckles under their fur, which show up as dark patches on their skin. It confused me, too, until the vet reassured me. If you really think this is more than that, take the cat to the vet and ask them. Or at least provide much more detailed photos, and point out the areas that you're worried about; I can't see anything unusual in this photo.